# Using same role account for sending messages to different apps

Tags: android, android-c2dm

We are working on implementing google c2dm service. My company has 2 android applications in the market with different package names. Is it possible to use a single role account id for pushing messages to apps with different package names? 
I'm under impression that, you need to register each  application (with a unique package name in android market place) with a unique role account id. Could some one please clarify this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Actually, using a single role account across all your Android applications is not only allowed, it's *encouraged*.

Answer (score 0):

When you register it asks about an app, but that's just because its only open to android developers.  It says right at the top for application(s).  In the registration just make sure that the app id is the same in both applications.

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", ap_id);        // your app id.
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "youremail@address.com");
startService(registrationIntent);
```

Both apps will count against the single message quota for the registered application.

Comment: Does this app_id needs to match with the our application package name?

Comment: I don't think so, but it needs to be the same for both applications.  You can use the example code to get the appid from pending intent, its a serialized object (I think).  I believe Google is just calculating a hash off the serialized byte string.  If they were just using the application package name, they would pull it themselves and not require it as a parameter.